# Status active inactive in jquery or angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs

## Status Active Inactive

when I click on status so one confirm box is open "yes" or "no" but without clicking "yes or no". when I press Esc button then it automatically change its value like active to inactive So that I have to refresh the page to get the previous value.

```
$scope.changestatus = function (id, eStatus) {
            var param = {
                aid: $scope.sliderId,
                token: $scope.tok,
                statusId: id,
                status: eStatus
            };
            var status = 'inactive';
            if(eStatus == status){
                status = 'active';
            }
            $scope.promtmsg = ($scope.general.ask +'   ' + status + '   ' + $scope.general.record);
            prompt({
                message: $scope.promtmsg,
                input: false,
                "buttons": [
                    {
                        "label": "Yes",
                        "cancel": false,
                        "primary": false
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "No",
                        "cancel": false,
                        "primary": false
                    }
                ]
            }).then(function (name) {
                if(name.label == 'Yes'){
                    $http.post(webservice_path + 'lession/changeStatus',param).success(function (res) {
                        if (res.Status == 'True'){
                            toaster.pop('success','',$scope.general.changestatus);
                            getData();
                        }
                    });
                }else{
                    getData();
                }
            });
        };
```

**So I need to put condition like if I am not selecting yes and no then the out put will be same as previous. So what will be the condition..**

Comment: You need to provide [some of your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: See my Code ......

Comment: Can you try changing the `else` to `else if(name.label == 'No')`

Comment: No it's not working ..

Comment: Try console.log('$http.post called') in your if block `if(name.label == 'Yes')` to see if status is really getting posted from this piece of code. I believe it's not this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Found the Right Answer

**While you creating your modal you can specify its behavior**

```
$modal.open({   
  backdrop  : 'static',
  keyboard  : false
});
```

> just add backdrop: 'static' and keyboard  : false
>   backdrop: 'static'
>   means you can not click outside the box.
>   keyboard  : false means you can not click any key to ignor the prompt dialogue box